# Access a variable outside its loop with Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, closures, nested-loops

I need to access a variable inside a loop in another function, with Javascript (not jQuery or other js frameworks).

Here is my js:

```
for (x in drinks) {
    for (y = 0; y < drinks[x].length; y++) {
    // testVarGlobal = drinks[x][y].name; doesn't work
        if (drinks[x][y].type == 'type') {

            txt['type'] = '<span>' + drinks[x][y].name + ' - ' + drinks[x][y].price +'</span>';
            document.getElementById("type").innerHTML += txt['type'];

        } // endif
    } // end for
} // end for in

function foo() {
    // on the next line I need the value from the loop - drinks[x][y].name
    var something = document.getElementById(testVarGlobal);
    return something.value;
}
```

Comment: Where do you call foo(something) ?

Comment: just outside the for loop

Comment: Where? It is not called in your snippet

Comment: I call it as a parameter for another function and if `var something = document.getElementById('someidthatexists');` it works fine but it's not enough as I will have to pass there drinks[x][y].name

Comment: Or not, depending on where he calls foo and where testVarGlobal comes from. @Chris - post more code and stop inventing functionnames

Comment: where you declare var testVarGlobal globaly

Comment: isn't testVarGlobal global if I do not specify var in front of it?

Comment: I can't just post the whole thing @mplungjan as no one would look at it; the example is simple to look over and I know there's an aha moment somewhere

Comment: See my answer. I do not have a huge aha right now with your use of testVarGlobal you are neither defining nor setting anywhere

Comment: you have to specify properly a variable in javascript by puting var infront of it. And it should be global if you want to access its value in other funtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell with the current snippet. Perhaps you mean

```
for (x in drinks) {
    for (y = 0; y < drinks[x].length; y++) {
        if (drinks[x][y].type == 'type') {
            txt['type'] = '<span>' + foo(drinks[x][y].name) + ' - ' + drinks[x][y].price +'</span>';
            document.getElementById("type").innerHTML += txt['type'];
        } // endif
    } // end for
} // end for in

function foo(drinkName) {
    var something = document.getElementById(drinkName);
    return something.value;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I cannot from the js you show me see what ID007 could  be but assume it is the drinksID here:

```
onclick="addToBag('+drinks[x][y].id+'
```

so you need

```
function getUpdatedQty(id) { 
  var prodQty = document.getElementById(id); 
  return prodQty?prodQty.value:0; // handle an ID that does not exist on page
}
```

and

```
function addToBag(id, name, price, quantity) {
  var quantity = getUpdatedQty(id);
```

To debug use

```
function getUpdatedQty(id) { 
  var prodQty = document.getElementById(id); 
  var val = prodQty?prodQty.value:0;
  window.console && console.log(id,prodQty,val);
  return val;
}
```

and hit F12 to see the console

If you have id:4 and need ID004, you can use

```
function pad(num) {
  return "ID"+("000"+num).slice(-3)
}
```

and

```
  var prodQty = document.getElementById(pad(id));
```

Comment: I will modify my code and see if this approach will work; will it help if I will message you with a link? it's a simple/small js file

Comment: http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~cdemet03/jvfmaa/js/scripts.js - getUpdatedQty is the function that will have to return the mentioned value

Comment: I've modified it as shown but the quantity didn't get passed for some reason; I am still playing with it

Comment: http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~cdemet03/jvfmaa/index.html - I get a 7, null, 0 - 7 is the ID, and 0 is supposed to be the qty - jvfmaa/index.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34840/discussion-between-mplungjan-and-chris-demetriad)

Answer (score 1):

```
var testVarGlobal = '';

for (x in drinks) {
    for (y = 0; y < drinks[x].length; y++) {
        testVarGlobal = drinks[x][y].name;
        if (drinks[x][y].type == 'type') {

            txt['type'] = '<span>' + drinks[x][y].name + ' - ' + drinks[x][y].price +'</span>';
            document.getElementById("type").innerHTML += txt['type'];

        } // endif
    } // end for
} // end for in

var somethingValue = foo();

function foo() {
    // on the next line I need the value from the loop - drinks[x][y].name
    var something = document.getElementById(testVarGlobal);
    return something.value;
}
```

Comment: I get a `ReferenceError: testVarGlobal is not defined`

Comment: @ChrisDemetriad, post more of your code so we can give more help. how are you defining testVarGlobal?

Comment: @ChrisDemetriad, depending on your logic, you may need to initialize testVarGlobal to something or otherwise do a check in foo() to mae sure it has a value before using it.

Comment: There might be no need for global vars depending on where they are needed. It is considered poor practice to clutter the global scope - especially if you just need to pass it.

Comment: @mplungjan, I agree, but as you say it depends. And as he does not seem to want to share any further code, it is an option nevertheless

Comment: I've defined it as per your example. Sorry for not showing more of my code, I am genuinely looking to learn more javascript and I rarely ask but this I can't get it to work; I just didn't want to post my problem and sleep for one hour - I want to understand it so next time I will know how to deal with it! this is a uni project - http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~cdemet03/jvfmaa/js/scripts.js - the foo() is actually getUpdatedQty()

Comment: @ChrisDemetriad, if you put `var testVarGlobal = '';` above the `getJSONValues()` function (i.e. outside the function), you will then be able to use it both in the `getJSONValues()` and `getUpdatedQty()`.